# Как установить cookie внутри body PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, cookie

Сайт на WordPress пытаюсь плагином организовать свою авторизацию в обход существующей (админы входят по WP авторизации, а пользователи для оставления комментариев отдельно). Возникла необходимость сохранять некоторые данные в Куках. Если в asp.net всё адекватно, то PHP выдал вот такой сюрприз:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
```

Я так понимаю, что к моменту, когда я сохраняю пользователя с помощью setcookie (форма входа реализована шорткодом), заголовки уже отправлены. Что делать и как побороть?

Comment: См. комментарий ниже. А краткий ответ на вопрос, как установить куки внутри body - никак.

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что функция setcookie() вызывается до того, как PHP начинает отправлять

Проверьте, нет ли в вашем коде пробельных символов, пустых строк или других символов, которые могут быть отправлены в ответ перед вызовом setcookie(). Такие символы могут вызвать отправку заголовков ответа до того, как вы попытаетесь установить cookie.

Если вы используете несколько файлов для вашего скрипта, убедитесь, что нет пробельных символов или пустых строк вне разделов  в этих файлах.

Проверьте, что у вас нет вывода сообщений об ошибках или предупреждений до вызова функции setcookie().

Comment: Проблема в том, что setcookie не может вызываться ДО всего. Она вызывается вообще в рандомном месте.

Comment: @GoodBoyAlex  это проблема вашего кода, не более того. Есть фундаментальное ограниечени HTPP-протокола: куки не могут быть установлены после того, как начался вывод на экран. Это проблема не WP и не PHP, она гораздо глубже. Поэтому вы должны строить ваш код так, чтобы выставлять куки вовремя.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, проблема в том, что код не знает в момент загрузки, какой будет логин или пароль. Как вообще это можно организовать? Может быть тогда лучше файл? Или запись в БД о cookie?

Comment: @GoodBoyAlex код знает в момент загрузки, что у него в POST. Подобные вопросы решены как в ядре, так и массе плагинов. StackOverflow не то место, где можно было бы провести анадиз вашего кода, и дать совет, куда что переместить.